# CSS Media Queries having no effect on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, browser, frontend

I am building a tumblr theme that needs to be highly scalable/responsive. It is pretty much just the posts in a centered grid. I am using CSS media queries to keeo track of the browser window size, to resize/center the grid accordingly. They currently look like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 640px)' href='URL.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 959px)' href='URL.css' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1279px)' href='URL.css' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1599px)' href='URL.css' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 1600px) and (max-width: 1919px)' href='URL.css' />
```

The first one, which Maxes out at 640px width, works perfectly when I resize a firefox/chrome window to be small, but seems to not work at all on mobile. My phone is a Droid Razr Maxx, and it seems to default to the 960px width, even in "portrait" orientation.

I tried having the styles default to the mobile-size style, but get the same result, and this is also less than optimal for other reasons (Internet Explorer being one.)

Comment: Your phone may not support media queries, you can get a library like Respond.js(https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to make it work on browsers that dont support

Comment: its because your phone has resolution of `540 x 960`

Comment: NullPointer -- Shouldn't the 540px resolution be covered by 'max-width:640px', or am I misunderstanding how media queries work?

Answer (score 3):

Put this meta tag in your html head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Many modern smartphones try to scale their viewports which throws everything off. This meta tag prevents this scaling.

Answer (score 1):

I deal with queries very often - the problem is sometimes what you see in the mobile browser isn't the exact amount of pixels a device's specs may say, especially if you're using any sort of zoom in the head. Something I like to do is check the viewport's/document's size using a very simple jquery alert to solidify exactly what dimensions I'm working with. http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/ is a great site to show you various ways to capture widths and heights of a viewport.

I also prefer to use 'all and ....' rather than 'screen and ....'

Hope this helps at all

Comment: Interesting... using an alert with document.documentElement.clientWidth gives me "980" in portrait orientation on the phone. Even though the devices specs are smaller than that. So do the media queries need the exact px width of the device to work. For instance in my comment above, resolutions smaller than 640 are not covered?

Comment: Yea, I've gotten some weird numbers myself before which is why I test everything before I go nuts wondering why they're not fitting into the query.. I also usually use "all and (max-device-width)" or "all and (min-device-width)" .. that might help you. Try those!

Answer (score 0):

Found this guy:
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/

looks like the "viewport" meta tag is my new best friend. Fixed it on my phone and my office-mate's iPhone.

Thanks for the suggestions!